# Why should I use managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

What is the benefit of using Managed Identity to access Azure services? What I often see mentioned is that thanks to this you don't commit secrets to configuration files. But I'm deploying all resources using ARM templates and I also don't have any secrets in my configuration files. Settings like connection strings are set during deployment. The only difference I see here is that with Managed Identity even if someone goes to Azure portal he will not be able to get login and password to my DB for example. But this person already has access to my subscription. So is this a problem?

What else do Managed Identities give me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not only about the config secrets that are stored or not, it's also about how many secrets need to be stored and managed.
When you create a managed identity, specifically a [system-assigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#how-does-the-managed-identities-for-azure-resources-work) managed identity, no one on your team will have to manage, or even have access to, the secrets related to the identity of the application. The identity is issued, and you are able to provide it access to various resources, such as key vault. No else will be able to use the app's identity take advantage of that access.

If you use a managed service identity in conjunction with something like key vault, you can also more easily limit the number of people that have access to config secrets. You can provide access to the vault to only a few, and still allow others to view/edit the app and its non-secret config.

Comment: basically what I was trying to say but you answered in a better way

Answer (score 3):

You're just seeing the happy path. What if an attacker exploit a vulnerability in your app and get the connection string, for example? If you use Managed Identity, he/she won't be able to impersonate your service.

Comment: and to avoid access to the subscription, always use 2Fa

Answer (score 2):

- Secret/key management. Rotating secrets is best practice. This is
  done automatically with Managed Identities. Complicated if changing passwords manually/scripting.
- Secret/key inventory. Makes it easier to see what apps have what
  permissions.
- Revoking access. Makes it easy to revoke access for a certain app.
  Can be scary to revoke access by updating for example a password.
- Granularity. Giving connection string access to a Storage Account
  will give full access to everyting in that storage account. By using
  MI/RBAC on resources it is possible to set for example read access to
  a specific blob.

Answer (score 0):

why not use encryption in connection string. Managed id sit on machine and can be compromised if some one can access machine.

Comment: I doubt you can do it on Azure. When to encrypt it? What if you deploy it using ARM templates? What if your app is scaled to run in multiple copies on multiple virtual servers?